ahk1:'a_priorKey' does not include whether mouse buttons were clicked?
I want to bind actions to my modifier key so that if I just tap and release them (without pressing an additional) they will perform an action. The code I achieve this with is:
LControl::
KeyWait,LControl
if (A_PriorKey="LControl")
   tooltip, Do "LControl tap" action
 return

But the above works for keyboard keys only, as in if I press ctrl+f the tooltip will not fire but it will if I press ctrl+lbutton, which I dont want. The issue is down to the variable A_priorKey only recording if a keyboard button was pressed, disregarding mouse buttons. The only way I can think of getting around this is as follows:
~LButton::
~MButton::
~RButton::
mouseButtons := 1
return

LControl::
KeyWait,LControl
if (mouseButtons || A_PriorKey="LControl")
   tooltip, Do "LControl tap" action
mouseButtons := 0
return

While the above works, its not desirable. I really dont want to ever bind mouse buttons in AutoHotkey or elsewhere.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
